# Two versions of Constant Q Transform (CQT) doesn't match each other?

Tags: fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

To my knowledge, there's two major CQT papers, the one by [Brown in 1991](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Brown91-cqt.pdf), and the one by [Schorkhuber in 2010](https://iem.kug.ac.at/fileadmin/media/iem/projects/2010/smc10_schoerkhuber.pdf).

The [2010](https://iem.kug.ac.at/fileadmin/media/iem/projects/2010/smc10_schoerkhuber.pdf) paper claims to be a more computationally efficient implementation of the [1992](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/628a/0981e2ed1c33b1b9a88018a01e2f0be0c956.pdf) and [1991](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Brown91-cqt.pdf) paper by Brown. (The [1992](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/628a/0981e2ed1c33b1b9a88018a01e2f0be0c956.pdf) paper is also an efficient version of the [1991](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Brown91-cqt.pdf) paper.)

I discovered that the mathematics behind the two papers are not exactly the same.

### Definition of $Q$ and $N_k$ by Brown in 1991 and 1992

$Q=\frac{f_k}{\Delta f_k}=\frac{f_k}{f_{k+1}-f_k}=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{1}{b}}-1}$ ----(1A),
where $b$ is the number of bins per octave.

$N_k=\frac{f_s}{\Delta f_k}=\frac{f_s}{f_k}Q$ ----(2A), where $f_s$ is the sampling rate.

### Definition of $Q$ and $N_k$ by Schorkhuber in 2010

$Q = \frac{f_k}{\Delta f_k} = \frac{N_k f_k}{\Delta \omega f_s}$ ----(1B)

$Q = \frac{q}{\Delta \omega (2^{\frac{1}{b}}-1)}$ ----(2B)

By combining equation (1B) and (2B), you can get the window length $N_k$ as below

$N_k = \frac{qf_s}{f_k(2^{\frac{1}{b}}-1)}$ ----(3B)

where $\Delta \omega$ is the equivalent noise bandwidth, $q$ is the scaling factor.

### Here's the problem that I have

If you try to equate (2A) and (3B) together, you will get another expression for Q.

$\frac{f_s}{f_k}Q = \frac{qf_s}{f_k(2^{\frac{1}{b}}-1)}$

After simplifying, you will get the follow expression.

$Q = \frac{q}{2^{\frac{1}{b}}-1}$. Which looks very similar to equation (2B) with a missing $\Delta \omega$ factor.

So, there's 3 different expressions for $Q$ now? To me, it seems a contradiction. Either of the papers must be wrong in their definition on $Q$.

Another mystery is where does the term $\Delta \omega$ come from? I don't see any necessity in adding this term. It seems to me the source of the contradiction.

Comment: While I don't know the answer to this question thank you very much for posting something that lead me to these articles on the constant Q transform! I've been trying to find good info on it for a little while now.